# Can i use nginx.conf in public_html

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx on my server and in my nginx.conf I have my web sites config.
If I'm put the nginx.conf to public_html for specific config it will work ?
Because I'm using wordpress and my security plugin put the nginx.conf to my public_html and i havent any idea about its work or not ? 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should merge your `nginx.conf` and the "security" `nginx.conf`.

You've possibility to [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) this "security" `nginx.conf` but I think it will break something.